# Rotating all OpenGL output

Tags: android, opengl-es, shim

External requirements --- you have to hate them...

I have an OpenGL ES game, which uses EGL and OpenGL ES to draw on the screen. I don't have source to this; it's supplied as a binary blob. I'm implementing the interface layer that mediates between the game's calls to EGL and OpenGL and the platform's implementation.

It works fine. But I now have the unexpected external requirement that I need to be able to rotate the entire game's output 90 degrees.

Can anyone suggest any good (easy, fast) ways to do this? Off the top of my head, I can think of:

- insert the appropriate transformation into the game's projection matrix. This seems to me to be the fastest solution; but I don't think I have enough knowledge of the game's manipulation of the projection matrix to do this reliably. Plus it'll confuse the game if it uses any OpenGL calls to access the screen which *don't* go through the projection matrix. (`glReadPixels()`, for example.)
- give the game a rendering context to an off-screen buffer; it renders there, and then when the game calls `eglSwapBuffers()` I copy the result onto the screen. Render-to-texture would help here. Problems: this will affect performance as I'm effectively doing two drawing passes instead of one; and render-to-texture isn't standardised in OpenGL ES. (My target platform, Android, doesn't even reliably support shared contexts.)
- render into the colour buffer, then use `glReadPixels()` to copy the data out and do a software rotate onto the screen. Problems: dead slow, and I have no control of the size of the buffer (i.e. if the screen is 640x480 and we're drawing 90° rotated, I really want to give the game a 480x640 colour buffer).
- other?

Game-specific hacks aren't an option here because I need to be able to swap out the game binary with another one; this has to be a generic fix. Changing the game isn't an option because we don't have control of the game source code.

Any suggestions? Other than the non-technical one of trying to persuade the requirement to go away?

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue with you have to use glRotate along the z axis ??
Approach 1 is the way to go.

Pixel operations are heavy and it is possible, that you could be messing up with the aspect ratio, etc etc.

The steps which go into drawing are
1. Set the transformation matrix (the model/  projection)
If landscape, apply the glRotate
2. Set the view port (this might change each time you rotate the screen)
if landscape - set a b as height/widht respectively
if landscape - set b a as height/widht respectively
3. Draw the matrix

When you rotate the screen, the objects are rendered again. So glRotate is the best way to go.

Comment: As I said, I don't control the game --- all I can do is intercept its calls to OpenGL. I don't have any control over the game's rendering pipeline, so I don't have enough information to do this.

Comment: can you set the viewport if possible ??

Comment: I can intercept the game's call to `glViewport()`, yes --- would that help?

Comment: Just a thought. Intercept the calls to glBegin and glEnd. do a glRotate before glBegin. Call glRotate again after glEnd.

Comment: OpenGL ES doesn't have glBegin or glEnd... and I'm afraid it still doesn't address the situation where the game's accessing the colour buffer directly.